# Java Socket Programming single Client-server

Tags: java, sockets

I want to create a simple chat program. But my requirement is some what different I want a single client - server type of thing. Means I don't want a multiple client server.
I am creating a server and waiting for client to connect. After client connects I am waiting for any message from client.
Now my problem is that when I run my client program, I can run multiple instances of it, but the only first client messages are delivered to server as it is single server client program. What I want is some sort of method with which I can limit other clients to connect and say display error message saying that server is busy try after sometime. Can anyone help me do that?

Comment: How about server accepting all connections and then for all clients but the first one (active one) send message  and close connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server should have a list of all client connected so whenever a new client connect; instead of just adding a new client; it check if there is already a user connected and if yes ; it close the connection/return special exception.It is up to the client project you made that decide how it will handle this closing of connection/exception.